# Android FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(); causes crash only in release version

Tags: android, apache, ftp

I am using Apache Commons-net-3.3 jar and have researched previous threads to make sure it is configured correctly in the build path.

My Android app works fine in debug mode on several tablets but when I release the code using Ant and publish it, the code falls over at :-

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

With no error message on the same tablets:

Code as follows.

```
      import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
      import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

      @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        File file = new File(mDBPath);
        try{                        
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            InetAddress mHostName;
            mHostName = InetAddress.getByName(mServerIP);
            ftpClient.connect(mHostName, mPort);
            ftpClient.login(mLogin, mPassword);
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(mWorkingDir);
            if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(file, mDBName)));
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    boolean result = ftpClient.retrieveFile(mServerFileName, buffOut);
                    buffOut.close();
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                    if (result == false){
                        return "False";
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    return "True";
}
```

My question is:- I don't understand why it works in debug mode on the same tablets?

Comment: Could you output the entire stack trace? One way of doing this would be to amend the try/catch with 

Log.e("StackOverflow", "Exception making FTP Connection", e);

Comment: Sorry people, I've been a complete muppet! I have a .net .apk builder to automate the ant builds and post the release version to an FTP site. I had forgotten to add the commons-net.jar to the build process.